# Spring boot junit test failed loading application context

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, junit, jhipster

When i run junit test on class MailServiceTest it works fine, but when I'm trying to do mvn build -B it fails.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = InstaticketapiApplication.class)
public class MailServiceTest {

@Autowired
private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;

@Autowired
private SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine;

@Spy
private JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor messageCaptor;

@Autowired
private MailService mailService;


@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    doNothing().when(javaMailSender).send(any(MimeMessage.class));
    mailService = new MailService();
    mailService.setApplicationProperties(applicationProperties);
    mailService.setJavaMailSender(javaMailSender);
    mailService.setMessageSource(messageSource);
    mailService.setTemplateEngine(springTemplateEngine);
}

@Test
public void testSendEmail() throws Exception {
    mailService.sendEmail("nemanja@test.com", "testSubject", "testCont", false, false);
    verify(javaMailSender).send((MimeMessage) messageCaptor.capture());
    MimeMessage message = (MimeMessage) messageCaptor.getValue();
    assertThat(message.getSubject()).isEqualTo("testSubject");
    assertThat(message.getContent().toString()).isEqualTo("testCont");
    assertThat(message.getAllRecipients()[0].toString()).isEqualTo("nemanja@test.com");
    assertThat(message.getFrom()[0].toString()).isEqualTo("InstaTicket");
    assertThat(message.getContent().getClass()).isEqualTo(String.class);
    assertThat(message.getDataHandler().getContentType()).isEqualTo("text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
}
```

Full code could be find here https://github.com/sansajn5/ISA-InstaTicketAPI , I'm using yaml for properites.Also I used structure as Jhipster generated project

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the failure.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).  Also, you should indicate what investigation you've already done to narrow the issue.

Comment: @TobySpeight as soon I get home I will edit it, thank you

Comment: please show the exception stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Normally you wouldn't load the `Spring` context file and then instantiate a component in a test via `mailService = new MailService();`

If you are writing a unit tests, don't load the `Spring` context file and mock all the dependencies of the component you intent to test.

If you are writing integration tests, don't mock dependencies, let the framework to load the context and wire dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line: `mailService = new MailService()`. Remove it.

In simple language let the `@Autowired` annotation take care of instantiation in jUnit using SpringBoot.